# Why do so many PCB-designers use non-metric units?

Tags: units

TLDR: Why do so many PCB-designers use non-metric units?

Sorry for asking this closed question again: [what is the advantage of non-metric units](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/178864/what-is-the-advantage-of-non-metric-units)

But I do not understand, and there is also no other answer for the linked question, why non-metric units used in so many places in electronic designs, for example for PCB and track sizes in mils, AWG for cables or copper thickness in oz/ft² (which is often written oz). And not mm, mm² or µm.

I see several disadvantages with imperial units or advantages of metric units:

- The SI-units use only Factors of 10^N, the imperial "system" have a lot of weird factors (like 12 for foot (for cable length) and inch (for track length))
- All complex Units exist only in the metric system like Volt: V = W/A = J/(s * A) = N * m/(s * A) = kg * m²/(s³ * A). And i think it would make sense to only use a single unit system. (so you don't end up with conversion errors or with a unit like H/ft = kg * m²/(A² * s² * ft) = 127/5000 kg * m/(A² * s²) ).
- Every one should know the metric system, but not everyone should know the imperial system. The Most imperial units are defined with metric units (example: 1 inch is defined with 25.4mm, so you must understand the meter before you can understand the unit inch).
- Every length written in inch or mils with a finite number of decimal digits can also be written exactly with a finite number of digits in a metric length, but not the other way around: (20 mils are exactly 508µm, 300µm are about 11.811023622 mils) (which can be a Problem when your PCB-tools use a internal inch-based grid).
- Copper thickness: in imperial units, the copper thickness is often written in oz, which is very confusing: oz are a units of mass (or one of many volume units). And you can not give a thickness in a unit of mass. There should write oz/ft². Which is still not very useful when you not know the density of copper. A thickness in µm is much more useful (for example, to calculate the resistance of a track).
- Some units in the Imperial System (like Ounce) still have significant different definitions and sometimes used for different physical quantity. For every metric units, the definitions did never change significant.

For the unit AWG, i see even more disadvantages to mm²:

- The unit only works with Natural number, when the wire is too big, the number do not go from 0 to -1, which would make sense, it go from 0 to 00. Which is unnecessary complicated, for example to handle it in a database (it is not a number, it is a string, and need a extra sorting algorithm (00>0>1>2)). If you use mm², You can just specify any real number and sort it correctly.
- The units have a wierd complicated formula of 127µm * 92^(36-n)/39 or 5mil * 92^(36-n)/39, with more or less random factors (92,36 and 39) (only works as long as n is positive), to get the thickness of a cable.
- With mm², the DC resistance is directly proportional to 1/A (A is the cross sectional area), and the maximum DC current can you estimate with about 6-9A/mm².

The people who start designing PCBs were engineers, so the did know all this things, why did they still choose to use imperial units? (It was even worse at this time, with more different definitions of imperial units).

Why i think this question is relevant for electrical engineering:

- The most common PCB-design tools, like Altium use a non-metric internal grid (which can lead to rounding errors).
- Shops labels there cables often in foot and AWG
- PCBs manufacturers often write there rules (for example minimum track size and minimum clearance) in mils or copper thickness in oz (when there really mean oz/ft²).

Comment: You can set the grid in Eagle to use metric units...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a rant disguised as a question.

Comment: I quite dislike imperial but use the imperial grid when layouting components with imperial based pitch (2.54mm, 1.27mm, etc)

Comment: @RonBeyer I talk about the internal grid, not the displayed grid.

Comment: @mkeith: I can't see anything "ranty" in the question. The tone is quite measured throughout.

Comment: The United States simply has not switched over to metric yet. Reference materials refer to the legacy units of AWG, oz copper, traces in mils, etc. But there is nothing stopping you from working in metric. I would also like to point out an error in your question. The ounce is a unit of either volume or weight, not mass.

Comment: @mkeith "The United States simply has not switched over to metric yet" and probably never will.

Comment: This is not the place for religious discussions. And you're wrong about one thing: Eagle does use metric units internally.

Comment: @mkeith not only, it is used for mass, weight or force, volume and thickness.

Comment: This rant is uninformed nonsense. Any decent PCB cad package can be readily switched between units, and any competent PCB designer working in the US market can readily think in both systems, **and will typically have to within the same board** as its a rare design that does not include components and/or constraints inheriting from *both* systems.

Comment: @mkeith wikipedia ounce: "The ounce ... is a unit of mass"

Comment: @ChrisStratton: That is me exact problem: why do we have 2 system when we could only use one?

Comment: The most basic reason is when we started out DIP packaging was king. As such, everything was on a 0.1" grid. 

Tools back then were also not computerized. Today you can make your grid and footprints any size you like, but back then things were designed with standard templates and stickers. 

As such, imperial units became the norm. 

Time has passed since then, and more metrication has slipped into the design world. But at this point, since everything is computerized, it really does not matter what you type in as a size, the software does the conversions for you.

Comment: 12 is far more useful than 10: more factors, can do thirds without a problem, to name but two!

Comment: In science books such as physics text books, the pound and ounce are force, not mass. Apparently there is some ambiguity over this point, and in practice pounds and ounces are used as mass anyway. The "fluid ounce" is used as a volume measurement. But the word "fluid" may be omitted. I suppose your point that the situation is ambiguous is valid. But in a technical forum such as this, an ounce is a force by default.

Comment: There is another legacy reason that is not valid any more. 30 years ago if you wanted it made and had your units in metric, the machine shop had to recalculate everything in imperial because the tools available, mills, lathes etc, were all imperial (at least in North America) e.g. One turn of this knob = 1/4 inch etc. Today NC machines, again computerization, make that irrelevant.

Answer (score 7):

As with a lot of electrical engineering, the answer is tradition.

For one: it simply doesn't matter which system is used. The only advantage metric offers at all is that units of the same measurement factor by 10^N. Well, an inch is 10^3 mills, so that point is taken care of. Other than that, you never need to convert between units for anything. Copper weights stay in ounces, track sizes and board dimensions are all in mills or inches (which, again is scaling by a factor of 10^N).

Two: On your AWG point, that also doesn't matter because wires are manufactured in discrete sizes. You don't need a continuous unit like mm^2.

Three: Most of this was pioneered in the US, where imperial units were and still are dominant. It would take a ludicrous amount of effort for very little benefit to the people who work on them. All our standards etc. are in imperial. If we converted them, then what? It's all being produced and interpreted by American engineers who are used to imperial anyway, so what good is that?

Four: Any complex calculations are not done by hand, they're simulated in software so again, there's no need to ever convert between anything.

Comment: America does deal with the rest of the world and while many Americas believe it is the centre of the technology world that is not possible due to the dispersed nature of production.  Having a single system would be convenient and in time this is what will happen.  In other respects your answer is very good and explains why it is not essential now and also why it will eventually happen as it is technically easy for the users to work in either system, as manufacturing partners request metric more users will try it and like it.

Comment: @KalleMP -  what you fail to remember is that most of the electronic technology you use today was invented in North America. Imperial Units were dominant in those early years.

Comment: @DwayneReid I do not think the 250M people in America are a superior interlect to the balance of the world population.  North Americans would have you think so but I am not convinced.  Your evaluation by inventions also shows up a lot of other countries in the mix.  The USA may have had more inventions per capita but the world is 30 times greater than the USA.  -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_electrical_and_electronic_engineering

Comment: @KalleMP : Please read carefully what I wrote. The point I am making is that because they invented the technology, the system of units they used became the defacto standard. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @DwayneReid, Yes, I did read twice before answerign you and again now.  My point, that I supported with the wiki link, is that a lot of stuff was NOT invented in America, I may be wrong but your supposition does not convince me.

Comment: This whole comment thread is looking more and more like a troll wanting to start an argument. I'm stopping now - no need to feed the trolls.